# rruleJS: Consideration of timezone for weekly case

Tags: javascript, recurrence, rrule

I'm using rruleJS (https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule) and have the start date like this:

Start date and time: 2015-09-15 23:45
Every 3rd Week
On the week days: Monday, Wednesday, Sunday

I save it and get this rrule:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=3;DTSTART=20150915T234500Z;BYDAY=MO,WE,SU
```

I would now expect the start time of my recurrence to be at 23:45,

```
Wed Sep 16 2015 23:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
Sun Sep 20 2015 23:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
Mon Oct 05 2015 23:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
Wed Oct 07 2015 23:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 

...
```

but instead I get these recurrences:

```
Wed Sep 16 2015 01:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
Sun Sep 20 2015 01:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
Mon Oct 05 2015 01:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
Wed Oct 07 2015 01:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
Sun Oct 11 2015 01:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 
....
```

It's because of the conversion to local time (CEST-> +2 hours -> 23:45 becomes 01:45). I can subtract the timezone offset but this would switch to another weekday. For example if I'd subtract 2 hours form Wed Sep 16 2015 01:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), I'd get Tue Sep 15 2015 23:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST).

But that's not what I want: The time would be correct but not the weekday. I don't want it to recur on Tuesday but on Monday, Wednesday, or Sunday.

How can I take the timezone into consideration but still keep the starting weekdays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, does your RRULE really look like

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=3;DTSTART=20150915T234500Z;BYDAY=MO,WE,SU
```

?

The DTSTART is a property, not a parameter of the RRULE.

Then for your DTSTART, what you want to use is a local time with timezone reference (FORM #3 from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 )

So you want something like:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20150915T234500
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=3;BYDAY=MO,WE,SU
```

Comment: The string of the rrule recurrence look like this. You can paste in "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=3;DTSTART=20150915T234500Z;BYDAY=MO,WE,SU" into http://jkbrzt.github.io/rrule/ (see tab RRULE String) and you'd get the corresponding datasets.

Comment: Maybe my response was not clear enough: There is no such thing as a DTSTART parameter in the RRULE property. The fact that one particular tool accepts or generates such a rule does not make it valid. Please have a look at the actual iCalendar specification: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3. Did you try the syntax that I mentioned in my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

We faced similar problems because we were storing our recurrence rules in UTC on the server side but were composing the rules using RRule.js on the client side. We still wanted to be able to generate dates on the client side for the user to preview.

Our solution was to create a copy of the RRule object with `dtstart` and `until` times offset to the local timezone. We used this copy to generate the preview dates.

We had to do this in several spots so it was easy to write an extension method on RRule:

```
RRule.prototype.toOffsetRRule = function () {
    var localRule;
    var offset;

    localRule = RRule.fromString(this.toString());

    var dtstart = localRule.origOptions.dtstart;
    if (dtstart) {
        offset = dtstart.getTimezoneOffset();
        localRule.origOptions.dtstart = new Date(dtstart.getTime() + offset * 60000);
    }

    var until = localRule.origOptions.until;
    if (until) {
        offset = until.getTimezoneOffset();
        localRule.origOptions.until = new Date(until.getTime() + offset * 60000);
    }

    localRule = new RRule(localRule.origOptions);
    return localRule;
}
```

Then, whenever we need to generate dates on the client side, we call this method and generate dates off of the local timezone copy of our RRule:

```
var localRule= myRule.toOffsetRRule();
var dates = localRule.all();
```

When we save our recurrence rule to the server, we actually store the string generated by `myRule.toString()`.